# If I take the hard drive out of my macBook Pro and put it in a non-apple laptop, will it boot?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd

I've just upgraded my (2011) macBook Pro to use an SSD. So I've now got an old hard drive laying around with OS X on it.

I've also got an old HP laptop laying around.  If I put the drive in the laptop do I end up with a 'hackintosh', or will something crazy happen?

Comment: You could swap out the DVD and put the harddrive in there as additional storage using a harddrive caddy.

Answer (score 6):

It won't boot, building a hackintosch machine takes more effort than just swapping a hdd.
Macs have a different bios than windows pc's and this is not stored on your hdd but in the machine itself.
Osx needs this special bios to run and "talk to" the components of your mac.
Also, osx might not have the drivers available for the components in your pc.

you could google for info to make a hackintosch

Answer (score 2):

There is a thriving Hackintosh community and some sites have lists of hardware they have found compatible. You could see if your laptop might be a candidate...

But really installing Mac O/S on a hackintosh can be quite fiddly and encourages hair tearing ;-) However if you like to fiddle around it might be a good project but the HD with Mac OS already on it, nope. To do a hackintosh you need to install from scratch with some special boot loaders that simulate the UEFI "BIOS" that Apple uses and tricks it into thinking it is booting on Apple iron.